# Инверсия слов автора, следующих после прямой речи: каково правило?

Tags: синтаксис, прямая-речь, диалог, порядок-слов, инверсия

Скажите, я правильно понимаю, что инверсия слов автора после прямой речи влияет на смысл текста, то есть с её помощью можно описать действие персонажа? Сравните.

1. *— Да, пора мне. — Он отошёл в сторону.*
2. *— Да, пора мне, — отошёл он в сторону.*

В первом случае персонаж сказал и после этого отошёл в сторону, а во втором он, получается, отошёл, говоря эти слова на ходу. Почему мы часто видим инверсию в словах автора (например, "... — сказал он"), и вообще, допустим ли вариант 2? Есть какое-то правило на этот счёт?

Comment: А вы уверены, что вариант (2) вообще нормативен?  Здесь глагол имеет значение действия, а не говорения. Какое правило допускает такую замену? !Ну это прежде чем об инверсии говорить.)

Comment: Не уверен, вот и спрашиваю. Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Мнение специалиста по этой теме: Я считаю неверным использовать не глагол говорения там, где должен быть глагол говорения. Меня передёргивает даже от таких часто встречающихся конструкций, как «Я тебя люблю, — улыбнулся он»; «Да ты мне ещё хамить будешь, — скривился он» (эти глаголы называются условно-атрибутивными) и т. п. А уж конструкции типа  «— Да, пора мне, — отошёл он в сторону» —  это самый настоящий косяк атрибуции, и в серьёзных книгах такого не допускают (https://blog.selfpub.ru/atributciya).  Поэтому вам нужно найти правило, где есть список глаголов-заменителей.

Comment: Возможно, это крайняя точка зрения, классический вариант. Сейчас в этой теме можно встретить и другие глаголы, но не стоит считать, что подойдет любой глагол. Это уже другая крайность.

Comment: Набоков и Есенин вполне себе успешно использовали глаголы "не-говорения" для авторской атрибуции. И смотрится это органично. Вместо того, чтобы тратить объём текста на очевидные и предсказуемые глаголы, дана многогранная картина.

Comment: На великих сложно равняться. У них безупречный языковой вкус, поэтому и  смотрится органично (кстати, хорошо бы примеры посмотреть).  А вот  в приведенном варианте такой органичности нет, поэтому это точно косяк. Значит, не исключены какие-то правила, рекомендации. Вот что нужно обсуждать.